# How do I prevent jQuery result to show up in two different forms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications

How do I get two separate results using jQuery in these forms? I enter information in the first form and the answer shows up in the second.

HTML:

```
<div class="span12">
  <div class="span4">
    <div class="row-fluid exercise1 one_rep_calc_container">
      <form>
        <div class="span4">Weight<input class="weight" type="number" name="weight" size="2" ></div>
        <div class="span4">Reps<input class="reps" type="number" name="reps" size="2" ></div>
        <div class="span4">OneRepMax<input class="one_rep_max" type="number" Name="oneRepMax" size="2" ></div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="span4">
    <div class="row-fluid exercise1 one_rep_calc_container">
      <form>
        <div class="span4">Weight<input class="weight" type="number" name="weight" size="2" ></div>
        <div class="span4">Reps<input class="reps" type="number" name="reps" size="2" ></div>
        <div class="span4">OneRepMax<input class="one_rep_max" type="number" Name="oneRepMax" size="2" ></div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The class `oneRepMax` is the solution form why the results of weight and reps.

jQuery:

```
$('.one_rep_calc_container .weight, .one_rep_calc_container .reps').change(function(){
  var weight = parseInt($('.one_rep_calc_container .weight').val(), 10 );
  var reps   = parseInt($('.one_rep_calc_container .reps').val(), 10);
  if(weight > 0 && reps > 0){
    var oneRepMaxVal = ((reps*weight)/30) + weight;
    $('.one_rep_calc_container .one_rep_max').val(oneRepMaxVal);
  } else {
    $('.one_rep_calc_container .one_rep_max').val('');
  }
});

$('.one_rep_calc_container .calc_one_rep_button').click(function(){
    var weight = parseInt($('.one_rep_calc_container .weight').val(), 10 );
    var reps   = parseInt($('.one_rep_calc_container .reps').val(), 10);
    var oneRepMaxVal = ((reps*weight)/30) + weight;
    $('.one_rep_calc_container .one_rep_max').val(oneRepMaxVal);
});
```

So how do I keep the results from the first form of oneRepMax separate from the second one?

Comment: You need to refer to `this` in your event handlers to you only operate on the one you're in, not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.one_rep_calc_container .weight, .one_rep_calc_container .reps').change(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parents('.one_rep_calc_container');   

    var weight = parseInt(parent.find('.weight').val(), 10 );
    var reps   = parseInt(parent.find('.reps').val(), 10);

    if(weight > 0 && reps > 0){
    var oneRepMaxVal = ((reps*weight)/30) + weight;
    parent.find('.one_rep_max').val(oneRepMaxVal);
  }
  else {
    parent.find('.one_rep_max').val('');
  }

});

$('.one_rep_calc_container .calc_one_rep_button').click(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parents('.one_rep_calc_container');
    var weight = parseInt(parent.find('.weight').val(), 10 );
    var reps   = parseInt(parent.find('.reps').val(), 10);

    var oneRepMaxVal = ((reps*weight)/30) + weight;
    parent.find('.one_rep_max').val(oneRepMaxVal);
});
```

The idea is to get the parent of the current element. That parent is the context for all your operations afterwards, with that way, you work only with the elements that are children of the current parent.

Answer (score 0):

You should give your inputs ids so you can refer specifically to each.

```
<input id="weight1" class="weight" type="number" name="weight" size="2" >
```

Then you can use

```
$('#weight1').val()
```

to refer to specific ones.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, you should understand that the jquery selectors select and operate as many elements that match the criteria you specify. Both of the forms have the same identifiers and so the Jquery calls the functions on both of them. As others have mentioned you need to differentiate the two forms such that Jquery only operates on the one you want it to.